# Having problem formatting random lines captured from a file

Tags: python, random

This code returns 3 random lines from a file. They are returned in a set and I'd like to print them out in a presentable format. How would you do this?

Here is the code.

```
import random

with open("/Users/will/Dropbox/zettelkasten/Super Slogans 202012281549.md") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line.replace(u'\xa0', u' '))
    sample = (f' {random.sample(lines, 3)}')
print(sample)
```

The original file looks like.

```
- Divided focus leads to divided results.
- Where I point my attention becomes how I spend my life.
- What is natural is not supernatural.
and 602 other lines.
```

Here is the output I get.

```
 ['- Divided focus leads to divided results.\n', '- Where I point my attention becomes how I spend my life.\n', '- What is natural is not supernatural.\n']
```

Here is the desired output.

```
- Divided focus leads to divided results.
- Where I point my attention becomes how I spend my life.
- What is natural is not supernatural.
```

I've tried without success

```
print(*sample, end="\n ")
print(*sample, sep="\n")
print('\n'.join(sample))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have some weird line endings.

This works well for me and uses one of the print statements you had tried:

```py
import random

with open("test.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line[:-1])
    sample = random.sample(lines, 3)
print('\n'.join(sample))
```

Content in `test.txt`:

```markdown
- Divided focus leads to divided results.
- Where I point my attention becomes how I spend my life.
- What is natural is not supernatural.
- Divsasdided focus leads to divided results.
- Where I point my attadasdntion becomes how I spend my life.
- What is natural is dasdanot supernatural.
- Diviadsadded focus leaasadaads to divided results.
- Where I point myadasd attention becomes hasdaow I spend my life.
- What is naturaladasd is not supernatural.
- Dividedassassss focus leads to dividesssd results.
- Whersssse I point my attention becomes hosssssw I spend my life.
- Whdsdasfasfaat is natural is not dfgsdfsdfsdsupernatural.
```

Go try it with that code and text file content in a Jupyter environment that launches from [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/HEAD?urlpath=lab/tree/demo) to separate out on machine or file-specific you have going on first.

The slice in the append statement removes the line ending. Which may be useful for you if you have weird line endings involved. You can just use the `strip()` method if you have typical line endings, i.e., for the appending use `lines.append(line.strip())`.
By also putting adding the line endings back in the final `join`, you avoid dealing with last line possibly merging because it won't have a line ending while the others will.

Comment: Thanks, @Wayne. This works on the file too! This doesn't address the `lines.append(line.replace(u'\xa0', u' '))` which worked initially to remove stray \xa0 hidden characters that polluted the file. I'll have to figure out some other way of removing them.

Comment: Could you assign the `'\n'.join(sample)` to a variable, such as `s`. And then do `s = s.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')` and `print(s)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
f = open("/Users/will/Dropbox/zettelkasten/Super Slogans 202012281549.md", 'r') 
sample = f.read()
print(sample)
```

Comment: Yes this will print the entire file in the desired format but I only want 3 random lines and when I change to `sample = (f' {random.sample(lines, 3)}')` I get a "ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative".